# Hijri calendar is 1 day too early.

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, hijri

how do I fix the Hijri calendar being 1 day too early?

Today, my-time = 23 July, 2013 Tuesday
And the Islamic calendar time = 14 Ramadan, 1434 (according to [this](http://www.islamicfinder.org/Hcal/index.php)

My calendar is showing 15 Ramadan instead of 14. However I'm not sure whether it is my fault or the site's fault. Anyone can confirm today's Ramadan date?

```
lblgreg.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Today's date:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

Conversion of Gregorian calendar to Hibri:

```
CultureInfo Hijri = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA");

        string datetoday_day = today.ToString("dd", Hijri);
        string datetoday_month = today.ToString("MM", Hijri);
        string datetoday_year = today.ToString("yyyy", Hijri);

        int month_check = int.Parse(datetoday_month);
```

Switch statement for value of months to be switch to text-month:

```
switch (month_check) {
            case 01:
                {
                    lbldate.Text  = datetoday_day + " Muharram " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 02:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Safar " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 03:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Rabi Al-Awwal " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 04:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Rabi Al-Akhar " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 05:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Jumada Al-Awwal " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 06:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Jumada Al-Akhirah " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 07:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Rajab " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 08:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Shaban " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 09:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Ramadan " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 10:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Shawwal " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 11:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Dhul-Qadah " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
            case 12:
                {
                    lbldate.Text = datetoday_day + " Dhul-Hijjah " + datetoday_year;
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Offtopic - but you should consider setting a local month variable that will change in your switch statement, and then set the lbl text after the switch **Edit** I also found [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hijricalendar.aspx) which may help you even more with all the conversion

Answer (score 6):

Use `UmAlQuraCalendar` instead.

```
var UmAlQuraCalendar = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
CultureInfo Hijri = new CultureInfo("ar-SA")  
{ 
    DateTimeFormat = { Calendar = UmAlQuraCalendar } 
};
```

Comment: default Calendar of culture "ar-SA" is UmAlQuraCalendar. Explicitly specifying UmAlQuraCalendar won't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

use HijriAdjustment and set it between -2 to 2
like this

```
System.Globalization.HijriCalendar hej = new System.Globalization.HijriCalendar();
    hej.HijriAdjustment =-2;
```

Comment: default Calendar of culture "ar-SA" for which the questions has been asked is System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar which is not the same as System.Globalization.HijriCalendar.

Answer (score 0):

*Check code below*

```
using System.Globalization;
//.......
var arDateTimeFormat= new CultureInfo("ar").DateTimeFormat;
arDateTimeFormat.Calendar = new HijriCalendar { HijriAdjustment = -1}; //set HijriAdjustment between -2 to 2
arDateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new []{"Muharram", "Safar", "Rabi Al-Awwal", "Rabi Al-Akhar", "Jumada Al-Awwal", "Jumada Al-Akhirah", "Rajab", "Shaban", "Ramadan", "Shawwal", "Dhul-Qadah", "Dhul-Hijjah", string.Empty};
lbldate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy", arDateTimeFormat);
```